# How to take advantage of historic data while doing churn prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, prediction, churn

The problem: Predict customers who will downgrade their bank account category 2 months in advance.

The data: 100's monthly variables for each customer for the last year.

At first, I thought I could take this as a times series problem, but I found it's usually better to take it as a classification model.
I can see, for each month, who will be gone by period n+2 and use that to train a logistic regression, or a boosted tree model.

What I don't know is how to use that data. 
I guess I could create multiple models for each month and add a "stays - leave", then weight the results in my final model.

What other good options are there to take advantage of the historic data?

Thanks!

Comment: Add lagged features?  My only worry would be that there will be a lots of correlation between lagged features.

Comment: @DemetriPananos that would work, as decision trees are mostly not affected by correlated variables.

Comment: You may get lots of ideas after looking at this Kaggle competition: https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-credit-default-risk/notebooks I my self was doing much feature engineering for this, and, yes, part of my input vector were time-distributed cunsumer behavioral features. Then you can well do with logistic regression, estimating the probablity of the churn.